# dispose of IO.File.ReadAllLines

Tags: vb.net, dispose, streamreader, .net

I am reading very large text files (6-10 MB). I am splitting the text files in to multiple new text files. There is common "header" and "footer" in the "read" text file that I will store as variable to be called at later time. I can't figure out how to properly dispose of IO.File.ReadAllLines. I'm concerned this will be held in memory if I don't dispose of it properly.

Text.Dispose or Text.Close isn't valid.

```
Dim testHeader As String
Dim testSite As String
Dim testStart As String
Dim testStop As String
Dim testTime As String

Dim text() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\anobis\Desktop\temp.txt")
testHeader = text(0)
testSite = text(text.Length - 4)
testStart = text(text.Length - 3)
testStop = text(text.Length - 2)
testTime = text(text.Length - 1)
text.dispose()
```

Later in the program I will be initiating another StreamReader and want to avoid conflicts and memory resource issues. I am new at coding so be gentle! Thanks!

```
' Open temp.txt with "Using" statement.
Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\anobis\Desktop\temp.txt")

    ' Store contents in this String.
    Dim line As String
    line = r.ReadLine

    ' Loop over each line in file, While list is Not Nothing.
    Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
        If line Like (sourceSN.Text + "*") Then  'Substitute in source serial number "xxxxxx*"
            file.WriteLine(line)
        End If
        ' Read in the next line of text file.
        line = r.ReadLine
    Loop

End Using

file.WriteLine(testSite)
file.WriteLine(testStart)
file.WriteLine(testStop)
file.WriteLine(testTime)

' Close transfer.txt file
file.Close()
```

Comment: What makes you think you would have conflicts and memory resource issues?

Comment: you could always save the header/footer to a Class or List so you can set the string array to Nothing and minimize memory consumption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to dispose of it. It returns a managed string array, who's lifetime is managed by the garbage collector. Internally, `File.ReadAllLines` is disposing of the underlying native file handle it created to read all of the lines for you.